# How can I build my own personal android app store?

Tags: android

How does one create a personal app store for Android built from either custom or open source software.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. I'm not sure why OP would want to do that, but I write apps for my company, and they do not want those apps on the google app store as the app is for internal use only. An app "store" sounds like a good way of saying "Employee A, download apps x and y. Employee B, you download apps y and z," then coding auto-updates.

Comment: Why was this closed? in a corporate environment, this kind of App Store is a must!

Comment: I think it was short-sighted to have closed this question.

Answer (score 7):

- Build a website using custom or open source software that presents applications so people can download them
- Devise a means for developers to register & upload applications
- ???
- Profit

Comment: ??? looks like "in-app purchase via the existing Android Market" to me, but then again, why would anyone do that... :)

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine you start with a server and place your apk's in the server then write a front side handler to interface between the server and the rest of the world. Then write an app to connect to the server.

Comment: I think he more specifically is asking for features such as automatic application installation/upgrades... like the playstore app does.