# Writing own Android Apps for personal use?

Tags: android

I am interested in coding up some interactive apps for personal use on my Samsung Galaxy tab running the Android OS. Ideally I would like to write a program in C++/Haskell/Python on my desktop, test them out with a simulator in an IDE such as Eclipse, and then transfer the compiled
executable onto my Tablet to be used like any normal Android app.

Can this be done? All sites I have come across so far are about writing android apps on your PC and then publishing them to Google Play 
after meeting some quality criteria as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html)

The closest question on SO I could find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613588/how-can-i-build-my-own-personal-android-app-store) one but it does not seem to answer the question.

If so, can someone tell me the workflow for doing this? In particular to which folder must I transfer my executable to?

Note: I will be coding these apps on Ubuntu 14.04 in the languages mentioned above.

Comment: Are you wanting to publish them to Google Play for your own use or would you be ok with just installing them?  Google Play is just for distribution and automatic updating.  You can most certainly download or install the app to the device just straight from a computer or personal server.

Comment: I would most certainly like to publish open-source apps to Google play for future distribution if my app becomes mature enough. Currently I just want to run the apps on my own tablet without publishing to Google play.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can build and run your own apps without uploading to anywhere.  Android allows apps to be installed from the computer to device using the `adb` executable (Android Development Bridge).  You can develop the app and push it directly to your device.

If your interested in python android you might want to checkout: https://kivy.org/

For more information on building apps and installing locally checkout here: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html